# Could not read from remote repository

Tags: oracle, git, servidor, localhost, virtualhost

Eu criei um repositório BARE na pasta:

```
c://projetos/cliente1
```

isso na VMBOX ORACLE que se chama (vmserver)

daí quando tempo acessar do pc real, retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> $ git clone file:////vmserver/projetos/cliente1 Cloning into
>   'cliente1'... fatal: '//vmserver/projetos/cliente1' does not appear to
>   be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

E se acrescento o (c:) mostra a mesma mensagem.

Answer (score 0):

No caso de não usar uma URL acessível você precisa usar a sintaxe SSH para acessar o repositório:

```
$ git clone user@vmserver:/vmserver/projetos/cliente1
```

Nesse caso `user@vmserver` é o que você usaria pra acessar a VM via SSH.

[**Getting Git on a Server**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server#_git_on_the_server)

Comment: obrigado, vou testar.